# Why fetch urls inside a for loop always return the same element

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch

I have the follow url `https://source.unsplash.com/featured/?nature,animal,street,world` every time that this url is called on browser, it return a different image. Right, I need called it some times to fill a array, then I'm using a for loop, however it is returning the same image to each idx of array... This is the function I used to fill the array elements:

```
async function getPhotos() {
    
    try {
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            let response = await fetch(apiUrl);
            photosArray.push(response);
        }

        console.log('length: ', photosArray.length);

        displayPhotos();//function that use each array elements to show a diffent img on screen
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

basically `displayPhotos()`looks like

```
function displayPhotos() {
    ...

    /* Run function for each object in photosArray */
    photosArray.forEach((photo) => {
        /* Create <img> for photo */
        const img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute('src', photo.url); //retrive img url inside response (item of array)


        ...
    });
}
```

But all item of array are the same, it should be differents... Why? And how I fix this?

Thx

Comment: `apiUrl` doesn't appear to change, so you should expect the same response each time (unless the API has strange behaviour which is expected to give different responses when requested many times in a row)

Comment: @RobinZigmond The URL does respond with a random image. But it seems like the returned image only changes after a few seconds.

Comment: @RobinZigmond it's a url that get random images, so each time that you try this same url on browser, it returns a different image... But Inside loop for, I don't know why, it doesn't work...

Comment: Probably as stated, they have a delay on each call. Only thing you can probably do is a a sleep in your loop between iterations or alters your code to allow it to progressively update.